# python is not installing dependencies listed in install_requires of setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have written a python module that depends on openpyxl. I want openpxyl to be installed as a dependency automatically using setuptools.
I read that the proper way to do this is to include the following in the setup.py script:

```
setup(name='methpipe',
    version=find_version("lala", "__init__.py"),
    description='Utilities',
    author='Jonathan T',
    author_email='jt@lala.com',
    url='https://git.com...',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'openpxyl = 2.3.3',
    ],
    scripts=["bin/submit_run_full.py"],
    cmdclass=dict(install=my_install)
)
```

So I packaged up my module with `python setup.py sdist`, took the *.tar.gz file, unzipped it, and then ran `python setup.py install`, and openpyxl is NOT installing!!!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Isn't there any error in the install log ?

Comment: I think you want to do `openpyxl==2.3.3`

Answer (score 8):

Try providing your dependency both in `install_requires` and `setup_requires`.

Following is from `setuptool`'s documentation at https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html

> setup_requires
>
> A string or list of strings specifying what other distributions need to be present in order for the setup script to run.
>   setuptools will attempt to obtain these (even going so far as to
>   download them using EasyInstall) before processing the rest of the
>   setup script or commands. This argument is needed if you are using
>   distutils extensions as part of your build process; for example,
>   extensions that process setup() arguments and turn them into EGG-INFO
>   metadata files.
>
> (Note: projects listed in setup_requires will NOT be automatically
>   installed on the system where the setup script is being run. They are
>   simply downloaded to the ./.eggs directory if they’re not locally
>   available already. If you want them to be installed, as well as being
>   available when the setup script is run, you should add them to
>   install_requires and setup_requires.)

Comment: setup_requires is "I need this at build time", whereas install_requires is "I need this dependency at runtime". Duplicating them in both places is not usually the right thing to do

Answer (score 1):

I notice when you use override 'install' with a 'cmdclass' key. The pattern below also left me with uninstalled dependencies.

```py
Custom_Install(install):
    def run(self):
        # some custom commands
        install.run(self)
```

Adding the dependencies into setup_requires didn't work for me so in the end I just did my own pip install in the custom install command..

```py
def pip_install(package_name):
    subprocess.call(
        [sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package_name]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Building with sdist create a source distribution, so I think it's normal taht dependencies are not packaged with your sources.

Comment: They are packaged with sdist :)