# Dependencies are not installed by pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, devpi

I have a library with the following `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

from mylib import __version__

requirements = ['paramiko']
tests_require = ['pytest']


def main():
    setup(
        name='mypackage',
        description='A collection of utilities',
        url='http://example.net',
        version=__version__,
        author='Me Me',
        author_email='me@me.net',
        packages=['mylib'],
        zip_safe=False,
        install_requires=requirements,
        tests_require=tests_require,
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have released this package to an internal `devpi` server. Whenever I try to install it, I get:

```
» pip install mypackage
Looking in indexes: http://devpi.mine/myuser/dev/+simple/
Collecting mypackage
  Downloading http://devpi.mine/myuser/dev/+f/a8c/c05e3a49de4fe/mypackage-0.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ee238ja7/mypackage/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        from mypackage import __version__
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ee238ja7/mypackage/mylib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .storage_host import StoraHostType
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ee238ja7/mypackage/mylib/storage_host.py", line 5, in <module>
        from .ssh import SSH
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ee238ja7/mypackage/mylib/ssh.py", line 5, in <module>
        import paramiko
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ee238ja7/mypackage/
```

Why is `pip` not installing the requirements listed in `install_requires`, in `setup.py`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296988/8472976) help?

Comment: @MegaIng thanks, but the issue is not related to this. See the answer by Sraw below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are referring your package before `setup` has been executed.

Pip need to first touch `setup(...)` to do everything. But before it, you `from mylib import __version__`. So `setup` doesn't execute at all.

Comment: Indeed ... I have the `__version__` in `mylib/__init__.py`, and reading that crashes `setup.py` ... I had not noticed this after refactoring because in my old virtualenv `paramiko` was already installed. After wiping the virtualenv to start from scratch, the errors started appearing. I am going to move the version to `mylib/version.txt` and read it from `setup.py`